# support multiple protocols on single server

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a working Express HTTP server as well as a working websocket server. I want to add the websockets application to my regular website which is run by the HTTP server, but I'm not sure I'm understanding the documentation. Can I have a server that accepts multiple protocols and how would I handle the routing in a situation like that? The npmjs documentation for socketio says:

```
In conjunction with Express
Starting with 3.0, express applications have become request handler functions that you pass to http or http Server instances. You need to pass the Server to socket.io, and not the express application function.

var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(){ /* … */ });
server.listen(3000);
```

can I handle HTTP requests through app.HTTPverbHere() and websocket requests through io.on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [socket.io documentation](http://socket.io/docs/) shows you the exact steps needed to make socket.io work with nodejs express on the same server.

So, YES, you can do this.

In fact, every webSocket connection starts with an HTTP request (which is then upgraded to the webSocket protocol) so you must have a web server running on the server that handles webSockets anyway.

socket.io simply hooks into one route on the express web server that is used to initiate all socket.io webSocket connections and handles things from there.

Here's one example taken directly from the socket.io doc:

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

app.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```